# Allow phone-users to save files from my website to their phone storage without using an app

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I have a simple HTML/CSS/JS website that is designed to be accessed with phones. It is not a native app.

I need to make a couple of MP3 files able to be saved to the user's phone SD card or storage. This is legal - the MP3 files are our own recordings.

I can only find solutions that require users to install 3rd party applications in order to download our files. I would much prefer a simple "click here to save this MP3 to your device" button (in the interest of user-friendliness :)

I have searched Google and SO and tried many different ways to word this question. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try with `DownloadManager` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864098/how-to-download-files-from-webview-android

Answer (score 0):

In Android browsers you could use the [download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) in your anchor tags. However, this is not yet supported in ios.

You could use a server side programming language to create a download page, but I do not know if that is possible in your app.