# Android WebView Download file on JavaScript trigger

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I've a webview setup in Android. The thing is that I want to download a file whenever user taps a particular element (like a video). I can attach event listeners using javascript into webview. But what do I do after that? How do I download file?

I tried to open the download URL (which starts the download on regular browser). But with WebView I get Webpage not available.

So it should happen like this:

Android --> JS executed on webview --> JS waits for user to tap a particular element --> JS somehow tells android to start download of a URL.

I'm not able to do the last step.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply made an `<a href="path_to_your_resource">link text</a>` element and it's working fine. you could probably use the webview client and implement `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. check this example [How to download files from webview Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864098/how-to-download-files-from-webview-android)