# Get video url from Facebook in WebView

Tags: android, html, facebook, video, webview

I need to download video from Facebook. In order to download video i need video url from `Webview` where i am loading the Facebook Page and user get login
I have tried following approaches to achieve this but none of its work

**1.**[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

**2.**[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864098/how-to-download-files-from-webview-android)

I tried to get video tag from html in webview but it didnt work because when we click on video on webview we are not able to get any html string

Following is the code i have tried so far in `WebViewActivity`

```
        public class WebViewActivity extends BaseActivity {
            private static final String TAG = WebViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                WebView webview = new WebView(this);
                webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                WebViewClient client = new ChildBrowserClient();
                webview.setWebViewClient(client);
                WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
                settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.setInitialScale(1);
                webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
                settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webview.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com");
                webview.setId(5);
                webview.setInitialScale(0);
                webview.requestFocus();
                webview.requestFocusFromTouch();
                setContentView(webview);
            }

         public class ChildBrowserClient extends WebViewClient {
            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                boolean value = true;
                String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
                if (extension != null) {
                    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                    if (mimeType != null) {
                        if (mimeType.toLowerCase().contains("video")
                                || extension.toLowerCase().contains("mov")
                                || extension.toLowerCase().contains("mp4")) {
                            DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) WebViewActivity.this
                                    .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                                    Uri.parse(url));
                            File destinationFile = new File(
                                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                    getFileName(url));
                            request.setDescription("Downloading via Your app name..");
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));
                            mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
                            value = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (value) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            /**
             * Notify the host application that a page has started loading.
             *
             * @param view The webview initiating the callback.
             * @param url  The url of the page.
             */
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        }

        /**
         * File name from URL
         *
         * @param url
         * @return
         */
        public String getFileName(String url) {
            String filenameWithoutExtension = "";
            filenameWithoutExtension = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".mp4");
            return filenameWithoutExtension;
        }
 }
```

Any Help will be appreciated !!

Comment: @Bro, can you please help me, i also in need to download facebook video from webview when i click on button, please help me bro, i can load facebook in webview but don't know how to download video

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "FBDownloader");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                if (swipeLayout.isRefreshing())
                {
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                                + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                                + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                                + "{"
                                + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                                + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                                + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                                + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                                + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'FBDownloader.processVideo(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\");');"
                                + "}" + "}" + "})()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
            {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function prepareVideo() { "
                                + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                                + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                                + "{"
                                + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                                + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                                + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                                + "console.log(i);"
                                + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                                + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'FBDownloader.processVideo(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\",\"'+jsonData['videoID']+'\");');"
                                + "}" + "}" + "})()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:( window.onload=prepareVideo;"
                                + ")()");
            }
        });

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

    webView.loadUrl(target_url);
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void processVideo(final String vidData, final String vidID)
{
    try
    {
        String mBaseFolderPath = android.os.Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + "FacebookVideos" + File.separator;
        if (!new File(mBaseFolderPath).exists())
        {
            new File(mBaseFolderPath).mkdir();
        }
        String mFilePath = "file://" + mBaseFolderPath + "/" + vidID + ".mp4";

        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(vidData);
        DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
        req.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(mFilePath));
        req.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(req);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download Failed: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some statement or explanation to your code snippet, that would improve your answer.

Comment: Brother, its working fine and download video while some time does not start downloading. I also need PLAY option in the same code, how i can play video, please please help me\

Comment: it doesn't work in case of multiple videos posted in a single post. is there any way?

Comment: in react native is it possible?

Comment: Its valid way to do? I mean play team accept this kind of stuff?

Comment: Recently I checked and found that it is not working, can anyone please check and help me ? Or something wrong from my side ?

Comment: This allows some videos to play and those videos don't get triggered for the 'processVideo' function. Any guesses on how to overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

Override ShouldIntercept method in webview, whenever you play a video, it will give you video link

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): WebResourceResponse? {
                if (request?.url.toString().contains("https://video")){
                    //use this link  request?.url.toString()

                }
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
            }


        }
```