# How to detect video is clicked on webview?

Tags: android

How can I know in `Android` `WebView` that video is clicked?

**For example:** When I run Facebook in web view and in it when I click on video Toast come and tell me that video is clicked.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your attempts so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `JavascriptInterface` to `WebView` and capture the click by `VideoObjectID` on your `HTML` page.

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
      public void performClick() {
        // Deal with a click on the WebView's Video Object ID
      }
    }, "video_object_id");
```

You `HTML` must have something similar to below:

```
<div type="video_object_id" onclick="performClick();">Play Video</div>
```

Comment: i want like this.

Comment: only want to know on facebook video click that video is clicked

Comment: facebook html is not like that

Comment: like this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586193/get-video-url-from-facebook-in-webview