# Canvas js export enable not working on android device

Tags: javascript, android, canvasjs

I am working on `CANVASjS` and build a sample app which is displaying data on chart. I have enabled `export` to save chart in `.png` and `.jpeg` and print also. While deploying it on `ripple emulator` the export is working perfect but when i deploy it on my `android device` it's not working. Below is the code part in which i have enabled export.

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("container", {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            zoomType: "xy",
            animationEnabled: true,
            animationDuration: 2000,
            exportEnabled: true,
// all other chart code 
});
```

**Update 1:**

```
 function drawChart(data)
            {
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("container", {
                    zoomEnabled: true,
                    zoomType: "xy",
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    animationDuration: 2000,
                    exportEnabled: true,
                    exportFileName: "Column Chart",
                    title: {
                        text: "Energy vs Date Time"
                    },
                    axisY: {
                        title: "EnergykWh",
                        interlacedColor: "#F8F1E4",
                        tickLength: 10,
                        suffix: "k",
                    },
                    legend: {
                        cursor: "pointer",
                        itemclick: function (e) {
                            if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                            } else {
                                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                            }
                            e.chart.render();
                        }
                    },
                    dataPointWidth: 20,
                    data: [{
                        //legendText: "EngergykWh",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        type: 'column',
                        //xValueType: "dateTime",
                        xValueFormatString: "DD/MMM/YYYY h:mm TT",
                        //xValueFormatString: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss TT",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        name: "series1",
                        legendText: "EnergykWh",
                        dataPoints: data                          
                    }]
                });

                chart.render();
            }
```

**Update 2:**

Bellow are the info images and a link of OS versions of android devices on which i have tried

[image]

[image]

[Galaxy j7 2015](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j7-7185.php)

I don't know what is the main problem of it. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using google chrome, but the export is working only on browser not on any android device.

Comment: You mean chrome on android, right? It is working fine on my Android device.

Comment: No no i am saying that when i run my application on ripple(chrome) then the export is working, but when i run it on my device (android mobile) it doesn't work

Comment: If not an android browser, then you mean as a native app?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell actually it's in `cordova`

Comment: What error you are getting? Please post it if possible.

Comment: @PravinD I am not getting any error i run my app on my device the chart loads successfully i click on the export button, it shows me three options `Print` , `Save as JPEG` and `Save as PNG`. On taping any of these options i am not getting any result i.e. i can't `print` can't save it to `jpeg` neither to `png`

Comment: Kindly provide device information.

Comment: @PravinD i have tested it on all `android devices` namely `samsung`, `htc`, and all other local + international devices but all show same result.

Comment: Ok...I was asking for it because what I was thinking is, there might be some issue with storage permission in Android 6.0 and higher devices. If it is not granted by user for the browser app, you won't be able to save that image to external storage.

Comment: So how to check this thing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129891/discussion-between-pravin-d-and-faisal1208).

Comment: @faisal1208 Im pretty sure that this is a bug, but id like to see your code,  could you post all your code for testing on my devices?

Comment: @Elenasys Kindly see the updated code

Comment: it would be more helpful to provide full code reference including all used plugins , a repository, or apk file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no Download Manager in webview that you have created, so you need to handle the download functionality manually. There are 2 ways to download a file from webview.

**1.Using Android Download Manager**

**2.Using web browser opened from webview (which internally uses Android Download Manager)**

The required permission includes [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Then set a download-listener for webview.

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength){
        //for downloading directly through download manager
        Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }
});
```

Refer the following Links for more info: [Link 1](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/11/download-file-videoaudiotext-through.html), [Link2](http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=10069050&s=Insides%20Out&ttl=Download%20File%20inside%20WebView), [Link 3](http://technoranch.blogspot.in/2014/09/downloading-file-from-android-webview.html), [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864098/how-to-download-files-from-webview-android)

Comment: How to use it with canvasJS in cordova ?

Answer (score 1):

When you tap the download option canvasJS is using the HTML5 download attribute to trigger the download, which works well in browsers that support it.

However when you tap the same link within your Cordova application, the webview it's running inside of doesn't know how to handle file downloads. Therefore nothing happens.

It looks like you could potentially enable this feature yourself by adding some custom Java to the app. Unfortunately I'm not an Android Java developer, but this issue might help you out - [Download File inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

Comment: How to use it with `CanvasJS` in `Cordova`?

Answer (score 1):

This **[plugin](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image)** should help you save your image as a download file.

Prodvided your canvas is "myCanvas":

```
Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(myCanvas, width, height)
```

or

```
Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(myCanvas, width, height)
```

Comment: How to use it with `CanvasJS` in `Cordova`?